# I am clueless why my variable keeps resetting to 0?

Tags: c++

I'm studying C++ atm but i stumbled on something i just can't declare why it is happening.
For no reason i am looking here for the exact solution of what i'm trying to do, just a explanation will be much appreciated!

It's about his piece of code here:

```
int Factorial(int x) {
    if (x = 0) {
        x = 1;
    } else {        
        int sum = 1;
        for (int counter = 1; counter <= x; ++counter) {
            sum *= counter;
        }
        x = sum;
    }
    return x;
}
```

So let us assume i call Factorial() with the int 5 (Factorial(5)).
Somehow as soon the program goes passed the if (x = 0) statement it resets it(x) to 0, atleast this is all i can see in Visual Studio since it hops from the if statement straight too the declaration of the sum integer.

I hope some can clarify me what the heck has happened here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `x == 0` .........................!!!!!!!!!#####^^^^&&*&* now you have a clue.

Comment: this *has* to be a duplicate.

Comment: At least he used a debugger!

Comment: You forgot to enable compiler warnings. That would tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yeah, i forgot since thats in every programming course, right...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(x = 0)
```

Needs to be

```
if(x==0)
```

At the moment, you are assigning `x` to 0 and then checking if the result (`0`) is `true`, which it will never be, since `0` is `false`.

Also, it is bad practice to modify the parameter variables. You can simplify your code and avoid doing this by changing the return values:

```
int Factorial(int x) {
    if (x == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    int sum = 1;
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= x; ++counter) {
        sum *= counter;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: lol, omg i must be so sleepy :D I also just noticed i'm asking for counter = 1 to eliminate the 0 factor of returning 0 and that fixed it too (since the if statement is eliminated)

I obviously should take a break :/ thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Thx again, and thx for not beeing so small minded! :p I know its a stupid mistake and all but going by the comments lol... Everyone was born pro, i forgot that bit.

Comment: "Also, it is bad practice to modify the parameter variables." - and this would also allow you to declare `int Factorial(int const x)`, which would have failed to compile if you accidentally tried to assign to `x`.

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers stated, it is because you need to change

```
 if (x = 0)
```

to

```
 if(x == 0)
```

Generally, to avoid this, it is advised to do

```
 if(0 == x)
```

because in this case, if you have only one '=' instead of two, it throws an error

Comment: Very interesting reason:)

Comment: This is clever, but I'm iffy about it...`if(0 == x)` just looks *weird*.

Comment: @Josh It does take some getting used to, but I've made a habit of putting immutable objects on the left for many years. It makes code much more maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it yourself.  `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

```
if (x = 0) {
```

Should be

```
if (x == 0) {
```

Comment: Hah thanks!! *sleepyhead* :/